# how to put coat of arms in the page background?

Tags: graphics, titles, backgrounds, thesis

I am trying to put a coat of arms in the page background as Lapo. F. More does in "writing a thesis with latex" https://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-1/mori/mori.pdf. However, I can't perform it in my current document.

I am using the following and I want to put the coat of arms in the page where the title is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, letterpaper, pagesize]{scrbook}
 ...packages I need for my document...

\begin{document}

\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\newpage
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\vspace*{0cm} 
\textbf{\huge My title!!!}\\[3.5cm]
\Large\textbf{My name!!!}\\[3.3cm]
\small Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of:\\
\textbf{Master of Science in Economics}\\[3.3cm]
Director:\\
Mr. something\\[3.3cm]
Line of research:\\
many...\\
2018\\
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

What package I need to use and what other additional commands shall I use?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in the linked documentation.
Here is the solution. (You should replace `example-image` with your own picture)

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany, letterpaper, pagesize]{scrbook}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}


\begin{document}

\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\newpage
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\AtPageCenter{\makebox (0 ,0){\includegraphics[ width =0.9\paperwidth ]{example-image}}}}
\vspace*{0cm} 
\textbf{\huge My title!!!}\\[3.5cm]
\Large\textbf{My name!!!}\\[3.3cm]
\small Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of:\\
\textbf{Master of Science in Economics}\\[3.3cm]
Director:\\
Mr. something\\[3.3cm]
Line of research:\\
many...\\
2018\\
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]